# Concatenate value of item with replacing the dictionary in the list of dict

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have several lists of dictionaries with same key and different values. In loop, if key is identical but value is different, I would like to concatenate value with delimiter `|` and replace the current dictionary, selected with the right key, with the new one with the concatenate value.

**Original List of dict**

```yaml
mylist:
  - name: openssh-server
    macros:
      - macro: SYSTEMD.NAME.SERVICE.MATCHES
        type: text
        value: sshd
  - name: apache2
    macros:
      - macro: SYSTEMD.NAME.SERVICE.MATCHES
        type: text
        value: apache2
      - macro: APACHE.STATUS.PORT
        type: text
        value: 9999
```

**Expected concatenate list of dict**

mylist updated with concatenated value (`apache2|sshd`) when the key of the dictionary is same but with different values.

```yaml
mylist:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  - macro: SYSTEMD.NAME.SERVICE.MATCHES                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    type: text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    value: apache2|sshd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  - macro: APACHE.STATUS.PORT                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    type: text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    value: '9999'
```

Q: "Loop over mylist to check if the package is installed with when: item. name in ansible_facts.packages"

Q: "In addition, type can be other value than text and should be if possible, retrieve from mylist."

Comment: You say: ``'type can be other value than text and should be if possible, retrieve from mylist'``. [edit] the question and make it [mre]. In particular, use different values in *type* and explain what value you choose in the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"**Concatenate value with delimiter `|`**"*

A: For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list_con: "{{ my_list_con|d([]) + [{'macro': item.0,
                                               'type': 'text',
                                               'value': _value}] }}"
      loop: "{{ mylist|map(attribute='macros')|flatten|groupby('macro') }}"
      vars:
        _value: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='value')|unique|sort|join('|') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_list_con:
  - macro: APACHE.STATUS.PORT
    type: text
    value: '9999'
  - macro: SYSTEMD.NAME.SERVICE.MATCHES
    type: text
    value: apache2|sshd
```

---

Q: *"**Loop over mylist to check if the package is installed with when: item. name in ansible_facts.packages**"*

A: Use [*selectattr*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr). For example, given the list of the packages for testing

```yaml
  ansible_facts.packages:
  - openssh-server
  - apache
```

the task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list_con: "{{ my_list_con|d([]) + [{'macro': item.0,
                                               'type': 'text',
                                               'value': _value}] }}"
      loop: "{{ mylist|
                selectattr('name', 'in', ansible_facts.packages)|
                map(attribute='macros')|flatten|groupby('macro') }}"
      vars:
        _value: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='value')|unique|sort|join('|') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_list_con:
  - macro: SYSTEMD.NAME.SERVICE.MATCHES
    type: text
    value: sshd
```